# Android, store complex objects without database?

Tags: android, database, object, data-structures, parcelable

I pass information around in my app with ArrayList and Hashmap a lot, but for persistent storage of complex objects, can I use some kind of "Parcelable" or something to store generic object types - that I can restore and stuff - without creating a database and doing the db management functions?

just curious thats all

Thanks!

Comment: depending on what types of objects are in your ArrayList it is possible that they could be serializable, which would allow you to store them as text into a file. If that is not an option you could likely use some other text based format to store them XML, CSV, etc.. Without knowing more about what you are storing though I wouldn't be able to get more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation :

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage

Like Tim said, make your object [Serializable](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/), so that it can be flattened.